# Python - ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a datafile of data that I used ascii.read to read into a python list.  I converted them using np.asarray so I could do computations using the values of the list.  Some of the computations end with a negative ln or a 0 in the denominator, obviously, this is broken. I am trying to do an `if else` statement if it is less < 0 then multiply by -1. If not, do the math normally. (I don't know yet if I just want to multiply by -1 or do something else).

I am getting this error:
`ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

I want a list/array as my output so a.any or a.all doesn't help me as I am worried about individual values, not whether the list contains it or not.

```
for item in radius:
subtraction = np.array(npi0/(npp - npb))
if subtraction < 0:
    tau = np.array(B*(np.log(subtraction*(-1))))
else:
    tau = np.array(B*(np.log(subtraction)))
```

I apologize if this specific issue was duplicated, I could not find something relating to my issue specifically.  I just started programming in the last couple of weeks.

Comment: Please fix your indentation, and which line raises the error?

Comment: `subtraction < 0` is asking if this array is less than zero, its an issue with length. You could iterate through elements of `subtraction`.

Answer (score 1):

To replace all values below zero with it's absolute just use a boolean mask and multiply with `-1` (or do whatever you want to do there):

```
subtraction[subtraction < 0] *= -1
tau = np.array(B*(np.log(subtraction)))
```

You could also use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and a function like `np.abs`:

```
subtraction = np.where(subtraction < 0, np.abs(subtraction), subtraction)
```

which creates a new array containing the absolute where the original array was `< 0` or the original value where subtraction did not satisfy the condition `>= 0`.

As @Robert Kern pointed out in the comments one doesn't need any branching in this case:

```
tau = B * np.log(np.abs(subtraction))
```

Comment: Just `tau = B * np.log(abs(subtraction))` will do. No need to do any branching with `if` or `where`.

Comment: @RobertKern True and I can't believe that I missed that obvious solution. I was more concerned about the more general approach how to process conditions and numpy arrays. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I will give it a shot!

Answer (score 0):

This value error comes up often - see all the sidebar questions.  Basically it's the result trying to use a boolean array in an `if` statement:

```
In [218]: sub = np.arange(-5,5)    
In [219]: sub
Out[219]: array([-5, -4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4])
In [220]: sub<0
Out[220]: array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)

In [221]: if sub<0: print('ouch')
...
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Which True or False is it supposed to use?  An `if` like this does not have any builtin or implied loop.

`@MSeifert` has suggested good solutions, but you should understand the root of the problem.

A good general way of dealing with cases where you want to do different things to parts of an array is boolean masking:

```
In [222]: mask = sub<0    

In [223]: np.log(-sub[mask])
Out[223]: array([ 1.60943791,  1.38629436,  1.09861229,  0.69314718,  0.        ])

In [224]: np.log(sub[~mask])
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:1: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
  #!/usr/bin/python3
Out[224]: array([       -inf,  0.        ,  0.69314718,  1.09861229,  1.38629436])
```

(I could refine the masking to deal with the `sub==0` case).